# How to create relationships between tables in Entity Framework&

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-core

I am creating a ASP.NET web API project (database first) and it pulls the data from the MSSQL database. Database have several tables but it is non-relational database (we cannot change it). What approach would you recommend for creating these relationships inside of Entity Framework?

Comment: Just map the relationship as usual (I assume you're not using migrations). It will keep you from using manual joins all over the place and you'll be able to use `Include`.

Comment: What do you mean by as usual? I'm newbie to asp.net (

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/da-dk/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key

Comment: Yes I have checked the documentation, I was wondering if it was suitable for my case, thank you!

Comment: What do you mean that it's a "non-relational database" MSSQL by nature is a relational database.  I think maybe you mean you don't have primary and foreign keys set up? Without having way more information no one here can help you.

Comment: @Canolyb1, Yes database do not have any primary and foreign keys set up, no relations. And I cannot change anything about that inside of the database. So, my question was can I create this foreign-primary key set up, in the asp.net without affecting the database? I have found Fluent API but it does affect the database structure as I understood

Comment: MSSQL is a relational database system. In RDBMS terms, your database doesn't have *foreign keys* between relations. But it is relational. That said, define the relationships using the fluent API. EF core won't affect the database schema unless you explicitly tell it to do so, which you won't.

Comment: I had no problems with creating the one-to-one and one-to-many relationships, but in the case of many-to-many, I needed to create link table and this gives me error of  Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid object name. I guess this is because of the new table that holds the keys of many-to-many relationship. I have been searching for solution but couldn't come up with anything @GertArnold

Comment: Is there anything that you would suggest me to look at? Thanks.

Comment: You should show this case as a [mre] for others to say anything sensible about it.